Why the result of pattern matching don't get propagated in some expressions?
I experienced this when I was trying to prove some lemma. Here are my definitions:
data OrderKind : Set where
    unrestricted : OrderKind
    ordered : OrderKind

  data Type : Set where
    unit : Type
    _⊙_ : Type → Type → Type

  orderKind : Type → OrderKind
  orderKind unit = unrestricted
  orderKind (T₁ ⊙ T₂) with orderKind T₁ | orderKind T₂
  ... | unrestricted | unrestricted = unrestricted
  ... | ordered | _ = ordered
  ... | _ | ordered = ordered

  data _⊨_  : OrderKind → Type → Set where
    ⊨⊙-ord-l : ∀ {T₁ T₂} 
              → ordered ⊨ T₁  
              → ordered ⊨ (T₁ ⊙ T₂)
    ⊨⊙-ord-r : ∀ {T₁ T₂} 
              → ordered ⊨ T₂
              → ordered ⊨ (T₁ ⊙ T₂)
    ⊨⊙-unr : ∀ {T₁ T₂} 
            → unrestricted ⊨ T₁
            → unrestricted ⊨ T₂
            → unrestricted ⊨ (T₁ ⊙ T₂)

Then there is the lemma that I want to prove:
orderKind→⊨ : (T : Type) → orderKind T ⊨ T
  orderKind→⊨ unit = {!   !}
  orderKind→⊨ (T₁ ⊙ T₂) with orderKind T₁ | orderKind T₂
  ... | unrestricted | unrestricted = ⊨⊙-unr {! orderKind→⊨ T₁  !} {!   !}
  ... | unrestricted | ordered = {!   !}
  ... | ordered | unrestricted = {!   !}
  ... | ordered | ordered = {!   !}

Now because I matched on orderKind T₁, I expect the type of orderKind→⊨ T₁ to be unrestricted ⊨ T₁ but it's still orderKind T₁ ⊨ T₁. Now I figured out that if I also put orderKind→⊨ T₁ then the type is refined:
orderKind→⊨ : (T : Type) → orderKind T ⊨ T
  orderKind→⊨ unit = {!   !}
  orderKind→⊨ (T₁ ⊙ T₂) with orderKind T₁ | orderKind→⊨ T₁ | orderKind T₂ | orderKind→⊨ T₂
  ... | unrestricted  | unr⊨T₁ | unrestricted | unr⊨T₂ = ⊨⊙-unr unr⊨T₁ unr⊨T₂
  ... | ordered       | ord⊨T₁ | _            | ord⊨T₂ = ⊨⊙-ord-l ord⊨T₁
  ... | unrestricted  | unr⊨T₁ | ordered      | ord⊨T₂ = ⊨⊙-ord-r ord⊨T₂

This way the type of unr⊨T₁ is unrestricted ⊨ T₁ as expected. Is there a reason why refinement only happens to the expressions bound with with?

You can generalise the problematic calls:
orderKind→⊨ (T₁ ⊙ T₂) with orderKind T₁ | orderKind T₂ | orderKind→⊨ T₁ | orderKind→⊨ T₂
... | unrestricted | unrestricted | t₁ | t₂ = ⊨⊙-unr t₁ t₂
... | unrestricted | ordered | t₁ | t₂ = {!   !}
... | ordered | unrestricted | t₁ | t₂ = {!   !}
... | ordered | ordered | t₁ | t₂ = {!   !}

See https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/with-abstraction.html#generalisation

I already wrote that in the end of my post. My question is why they need to be bound using with abstraction?

How else would it work? Generalisation doesn't make Agda magically rewrite things in the type of every subterm.

I am curious the reason behind it. It's the first time that I am hearing about generalisation. Thanks for the link I will read it further.

Actually, I agree this is somewhat surprising: in Coq, you do this sort of things (generalising over a variable to "update" its type) all the time, because pattern-matching is very dumb (usually tactics are the ones doing the dirty job though, a user mostly doesn't see it). But my mental model of Agda's pattern-matching is that it is smart enough to do this (meaning: propagating informations about a pattern-match scrutinee in other terms mentioning this scrutinee) "automatically". I guess the with pattern is complicated enough that Agda is not able to handle this without a little help?
